# Taking picture without camera preview not working in lollipop and above version

Tags: android

The following code works fine in android version less than lollipop but in lollipop and above version its not working. Can Anybody help what to do so that it can work in all the versions. I have tested it in many devices, but in lollipop im getting this error `"takePicture failed"`.

```
public class CameraService extends Service {
    private Camera camera;
    private int cameraId = 0;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        capureImage();
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    public void capureImage() {
        try {
            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId < 0) {
            } else {
                SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
                safeCameraOpen(cameraId);
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
                camera.startPreview();
                Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setJpegQuality(100);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                        data.length);
                saveBitmap(bitmapPicture);
                releaseCamera();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        String _time = "";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int millisecond = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hourofday = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        _time = "image_" + hourofday + "" + minute + "" + second + ""
                + millisecond;
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/DiaryFakeImage";
        try {
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, _time);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error in saving image", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
        boolean qOpened = false;
        try {
            releaseCamera();
            camera = Camera.open(id);
            qOpened = (camera != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return qOpened;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You necessarily must use a preview but... you can use a preview with `1x1px`

Comment: How to use it can you add code in comment

Comment: you still need the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SurfaceTexture for Lollipop.

Try adding this just before `camera.startPreview();`-

```
SurfaceTexture st = new SurfaceTexture(MODE_PRIVATE);
camera.setPreviewTexture(st);
camera.startPreview();
```

Comment: Thank You so much now this is working fine in all devices.